# Solving ODE problem with calculator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

I'm trying to solve a below ODE problem with TI-nspire cas:

$$
y''-4y'+3y=cos^2x
$$

If I solve the above problem by hand (or using the wolfram alpha), I get the

$$
y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{3x}+\frac16-\frac{1}{130}(cos 2x+8sin2x)
$$
However, when I solve this with Ti-nspire cas, gives the following answer:
$$
y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{3x}+\frac{31}{195}-\frac{8sin(x)cos(x)}{65}+\frac{sin(x)^2}{65}
$$
I type in the calculator as follows:
$$
desolve(y''-4y'+3y=(cos(x))^2,x,y)
$$
Is there any problem with my input? Or is the calculator failing to solve this?

I look forward to some help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to write $e^{x}$ and $e^{3x}$ instead of $x^x$ and $x^{3x}$.

Comment: And I think you typo'd one off the signs there (on $\cos 2 x$)

Comment: Oh yeah, Dave, you're completely right, I've edited the text. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Batman, I think it 's all right now.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put backslashes before functions they come out in the correct font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x giving $sin x$

Answer (score 2):

Use the trigonometric identities $\cos(2x) = 1-2 \sin^2 x $ and $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$.

You can check your answer by plugging each solution into the original ODE and seeing if it is true.